# VBulletin Change Registration URL

Tags: php, wordpress, vbulletin

I'm trying to connect a VBulletin site to a Wordpress installation so when you create WP account it automatically creates one for the forums. I already found a way to do that, now all I need is to change the registration URL for the forums to point to the wordpress site.
I understand this has to be  done by changing the code, but for the life of me I can't find the right file.

Where do I need  to change this?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention your vBulletin version which makes it hard to help you. 
A solution for vBulletin 4 to rename the registration url can be found on http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=297834